# How do I allow user do do certain things in an app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I know that the answer is google it... I spent 3 days on google with not finding what I wanted.

I am trying to develope a program, let me tell you what:

Well I use the Visual Basic Application Form in Visual Studio 2010 express..

I had an very cool Idea with a program where a user would have buttons, a button will have a name: emaple: google. When they click on the button, it will semd the user to google.com on their main browser.

Now, my problem is that I have no clue on how to allow the user to add their own links.

By default there can be google, but I want the user to add their own link and have to possibility to delete them as well... I thought of using an extra file (.txt) where the app will read data from there but I found it a bit too complicated for user.

So, what my question is?

Is there a way I can allow user to input their own link and button name??

Thank You,
Pavel

Comment: There are a lot of ways, you can use My.Settings infrastructure, or just use a ListBox to add/delete urls and serialize/deserialize the items when your app starts. 3 days spent on Google?, come on... search about My.Settings (or settings for C#) or Data Serialization, both solutions are very easy to understand, and are explained with examples in MSDN and in thousands of Google results.

Comment: ElektroStudios, a priciate your answer. For now as what it is, I am a beginner with HUGE imagination. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'll give you some links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx as you can see there are Binary and Xml serialization possibilities (there is a JSon serializer too). And about My.Settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611%28v=vs.80%29.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wch2c4sf.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

Comment: The thing is that, you let the user add urls in a random control (like a ListBox), then you construct a String array with that, you serialize the array data to a local file when the collection changes using your preferred serializer, and deserialize the array data from local file when the app starts. This is one way to do it.

Comment: ElektroStudios, Thank You.. You helped me alot, I will get back to the project in the morning (czech time:22:minute). I apriciate your help in a very big way! You are awesome.